# Head content are in body wp theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I make a WordPress theme! But There is a white space bar in top of my page! and I cannot hide it! and when I see my code with inspect Element that will show my head tag content in body! This is inspect Element show:

```
<title>aa</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/wordpress2/wp-content   /plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css?v=3.3.7"   type="text/css" media="all">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and I do  before !

Answer (score 0):

Very little to go on here OP.

First question,

Did you hardcode `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/wordpress2/wp-content   /plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css?v=3.3.7"   type="text/css" media="all">` yourself?

Second question,

If it's CSS related, but you are not sure what is the root it, can you inspect the element and apply `display:none` and see if it the whitespace is removed.

Finally, expand on your original post, a screenshot would help, how are you loading files? What does your `header.php` look like and what does your `functions.php` look like. Otherwise we can't do much here

Comment: in view source is ok! but in inspect element not!

Comment: Have you tried the above OP? Can you update your original post with more details. I can't help you without more info